# Share code among multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, architecture, gesture, viewcontroller

I have got 2 view controller that do different things in general, but they share similar behavior on some gestures (i.e. double tapping the screen).

Right now each view controller has a bunch of code to setup the GestureRecognizer and to handle the detected gestures. But this code is almost the same for both classes.

How can I have some of the code to be shared among the 2 view controller in a different class (i.e. the handling of the gestures)?

Answer (score 0):

Create a view controller with all the shared code and make the 2 view controllers its subclasses?

Comment: not possible because both view controllers are subclasses of different view controllers... complex structure and I can do nothing about that... thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

You could add the shared code as a category on `UIViewController`?

Comment: This should probably be a comment on the post unless you can expand on why this is a reasonable answer.